# Find inverse operator

Tags: operator-theory, special-functions

Let $D=\dfrac{d}{dx}.$  Consider the operator
$$
D_{h,x}=\frac{e^{hD}-1}{h}.
$$

**Question.**  What is explicit form of the operator $D^{-1}_{h,x}?$

I think that 
$$
D^{-1}_{h,x}=\frac{h}{e^{hD}-1},
$$
is wrong answer.

Comment: You might want to look at how these ops are related to the exponential generating function for the  Bernoulli numbers and to the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{I} = D^{-1}$ then wouldn't
$$
D^{-1}_{h,x}[f] = \mathcal{I} \left[ \frac{\ln(fh+1)}{h} \right],
$$

because then
$$
D^{-1}_{h,x}\left[D_{h,x}[f]\right] = f?
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a correct answer: $$e^{hD}f = \sum \frac{h^n}{n!}D^n f = f(x+h)$$ so $$D_{h,x}f = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Given $$g(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ we may reconstruct $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = h\sum_{n=1} g(x - nh)$$

Now $g(x - nh) = e^{-nhD}g$, that is $$f = h\sum e^{-nhD}g = h\sum (e^{-hD})^n g= h(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-hD}} - 1)g = \frac{h}{e^{hD} - 1}g$$

All convergence considerations aside, of course.

PS: I don't know what I was thinking before. Thank @Leox for pointing out.

Comment: but in yours notation I got  that $$g(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-h f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: @Leox I don't see how you got that. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: Suppose  that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1} h^n g(x - nh),$$ or $$f(x)=hg(x-h)+h^2g(x-2h)+h^3g(x-3h)+\cdots.$$ Then $$f(x+h)=hg(x)+h^2g(x-h)+h^3g(x-2h)+\cdots.$$ Thus $$\frac{f(x+h)}{h}=g(x)+hg(x-h)+h^2g(x-2h)+h^3g(x-3h)+\cdots=g(x)+f(x).$$ It follows now that $$g(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-hf(x)}{h}$$  but  not $$g(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ as was promised.

Comment: @Leox Than you. I don't know what I was thinking. Surprisingly the result holds.

Answer (score 1):

The op $D^{-1}D_{h,x}$ and its inverse $DD_{h,x}^{-1}$ are classic operators associated with the Bernoulli numbers (and polynomials) and the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Comment: what kind of the association? The e.g.f. for the Bernoulli numbers is $$\frac{h}{e^h-1}.$$ How it  can helpto get the inverse function?

Comment: See, for example, https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/appells-for-the-bernoullis/#more-698 . This has more detail than you would probably like or need but indicates the importance of these operators. Or, for conciseness, see Henry Cohn's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61252/why-do-bernoulli-numbers-arise-everywhere .

Comment: Be careful not to use confusing terminology. Inverse operator is not equal to inverse function. The inverse op is generally a multiplicative inverse and the inverse function, either a multiplicative or compositional inverse.

Comment: Also, Cohn is a little lax in his notation.

Answer (score 0):

$D^{-1}_{h,x}(f) = e^{-h\frac{d}{dx}}(hf+1)$